# Why is the Django API returning an empty array

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, rest

I am developing a web application using Django but I am  not getting the desired results, the Django API is return an empty array ([]). This is the serializer class I am trying to get the places data ->

```
from rest_framework import  serializers
from . import models

class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = models.Place
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')
```

These  are the views ->

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .import models, serializers

# Create your views here.


class PlaceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PlaceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Place.objects.filter(owner_id=self.request.user.id)
    # Only the owner can create or make changes on the places

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Check your get_queryset. It's returning empty [] that's why your api is returning empty result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with how you wrote your queryset. Assuming your `Place` model has an `owner` field that is a foreign key to the `User` model, you should adjust your `get_queryset` model as follows:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Place.objects.filter(owner__id=self.request.user.id)  # notice the double underscore in owner__id
```

Or you could simply write it as:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Place.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

### Update

Make sure to be authenticated first. For an unauthenticated user, the `request.user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser` and doesn't has an `id` field. Define your authentication scheme using either:

- Using an `authentication_classes` attribute in your view.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication

class PlaceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PlaceSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Place.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Or

- Using the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` dictionary in the settings module.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

@Eyob Tariku here is the Place model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Place(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number_of_tables = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.owner.username, self.name)
```

Comment: I tried that still getting the same results.

Comment: I think this can be due to an authentication issue. So I have have updated my answer accordingly. But if the solution is still not working, could you also include your `Place` model on the question so we could have a better understanding of the structure?

Comment: thanks for your reply I included  the Place model above.

Comment: I can't see the model above.

Comment: @Eyok Tariku -> Kindly see this link the class named Place https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233618/8887187

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you call the api while authenticated ? cause as far as i can see there is no problem in your codes . when your view needs to have authentication , then you need to assign the permission classes(if you didn't set default permission classes in settings.py) . i believe if you call the api while authenticated there should be no problem.